# Как правильно выровнять элементы по вертикальному центру в меню bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, css3, bootstrap

Есть классическое меню с логотипом бренда на `bootstrap`. [Фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/kcpma/791/) Для текущего размера картинки логотипа - размер по дизайну должен быть **88px**. Как сделать так, чтобы независимо от размеров лого оно каждый раз выравнивалось вместе с меню по вертикальному центру (с аналогичными отступами) и при этом было кроссбраузерным ie8+? Употребление в данном случае `padding`, `marging`, `line-height`, `position:absolute` - дурной тон. Пробовал оборачивать `<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">` с комбинацией `table-table-cell-vervical-align-middle`, но почему-то не срабатывает.. Как быть?

```css
.navbar {
  height: 88px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css">
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Header -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/66x61">Bootstrap 3 Skeleton
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Navbar Links -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>







<!-- Post Info -->
<div style='position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0; background:lightgray;width:100%;'>
  Find documentation:
  <a href='http://getbootstrap.com/css/'>
        Get Bootstrap 3
    </a>
  <br/>Fork This Skeleton Here:
  <a href='http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/kcpma/'>
        Bootstrap 3 Skeleton
    </a>
  <br/>
</div>
```

Comment: Я бы предложил флексы,  но старые браузеры сразу пойдут лесом

Comment: @tutankhamun, да - вот именно поэтому я изначально и указал в описании, что нужен кроссбраузерный вариант

Comment: Для полноты вопроса было бы неплохо уточнить что в вашем понимании означает "кроссбраузерный". Работать везде одинаково точно не будет (попробуйте эту задачу на IE3 выполнить :))

Comment: @tutankhamun а с ie3 реально еще зайти в нет? достаточно будет ie8+. когда-то уже встречал правильное решение этого вопроса - не помню правда, что оно из себя представляло. если обнаружу - сам здесь опубликую